# Using ASP.NET Identity via WEB API for local login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I want to use ASP.NET identity for a project that is set up using MVC5 on the front end with a physically separated Business Logic server. The BL server is the only one with direct access to the DB server.

In order to set this up I thought I could go one of two ways:

1. Use ASP.NET Identity from the front-end, but use a custom IUser*Store to make calls to a Web API instead of direct to the DB. The Web API would run on the BL server and implement the data access (EF).
2. Use ASP.NET Identity from the BL via a WEB API, but have it serve up DTOs (really, just the models that would be passed to the Views). The MVC layer would just call the Web API with data from the ViewModels, and then the Web API would return the models that would be passed in to the Views (The MVC layer really just becomes a pass-through). I may use a DTO that differs slightly from the ViewModel, then just have the MVC layer create the ViewModel, but it doesn't change the overall point.

I thought perhaps the first option was cleaner, but how do I use claims authorization on that backend Web API? I want to be able to pass it some kind of token? Who generates it, and how do I get the Web API to work with it (that is, pull out the access_token from the header and create a ClaimsPrincipal)?

The concern I have over the second option is that it doesn't have a direct login call, it just has the token support, so I don't know if I can still manage the user's login state in the same way or if I should be doing it this way at all (I need full access to regular user management stuff like changing password, two-factor, lockout accounts, etc.)

Any guidance on the correct approach to take would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with option 1. I make Web API calls from IUser*Store implementations.

I solved the ClaimsPrincipal issue by issuing an access_token using IdentityServer. Web API easily works with these tokens and builds my ClaimsPrincipal for me, then I can use the claims however I want. In my case, I use an AuthorizationManager for centralized access checking.

I hope this helps!